# Field Homomorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Suppose $F$ is a field and $R$ is a ring. The function $f\colon F\to R$ is a surjective homomorphism. Prove that $R$ is either the trivial ring, or $R$ is isomorphic to $F$.

Comment: Any thoughts of your own?

Comment: hint: the image of an invertible element is invertible (why?)

Comment: Hint: by the first isomorphism theorem the image is characterized by the kernel, for which there are only two choices in a field, the ideals $(0)$ and $(1).\ \ $

Comment: Consider the kernel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have a ring homomorphism $f : F \to R$ here are the key facts:

- the inverse image of an ideal is an ideal.
- the only ideals of a field $F$ are $(0)$ and $F$.
- the kernel of a ring homomorphism is an ideal.

Take the inverse image of the kernel, if it's $(0)$ the rings are isomorphic. If it's $F$ the homomorphism is trivial.